# Quanteda: Create ngrams and skipgrams from tokens in R

Tags: r, n-gram, quanteda

I have been browsing the quanteda package in R and could not figure out completely how tokens_skipgrams functions. Below is [the example from the manual of this package](https://docs.quanteda.io/reference/tokens_ngrams.html) that I am not quite sure I have understood it well:

```
tokens_skipgrams(toks, n = 3, skip = 0:2, concatenator = " ")   
tokens from 1 document.
text1 :
[1] "insurgents killed in"        "insurgents killed ongoing"  
[3] "insurgents killed fighting"  "insurgents in ongoing"      
[5] "insurgents in fighting"      "insurgents ongoing fighting"
[7] "killed in ongoing"           "killed in fighting"         
[9] "killed ongoing fighting"     "in ongoing fighting"
```

I would expect that the output to be comprised of the following:

```
 "insurgents killed in"    "killed in ongoing"    "in ongoing fighting" 
 "insurgents in fighting"
```

Why does the result include:

```
  "insurgents killed ongoing"  
  "insurgents killed fighting"  
  "insurgents in ongoing"      
  "insurgents ongoing fighting"
  "killed in fighting"         
  "killed ongoing fighting"
```

In the example above, skip = 0:2 that is skip is 0, 1, and 2. Therefore, I thought the command above can be safely broken into 3 pieces and the combination of each would give me the result above which as I indicated I could not get.

```
tokens_skipgrams(toks, n = 3, skip = 0, concatenator = " ")   
tokens from 1 document.
text1 :
[1] "insurgents killed in" "killed in ongoing"    "in ongoing fighting" 

tokens_skipgrams(toks, n = 3, skip = 1, concatenator = " ")   
tokens from 1 document.
text1 :
[1] "insurgents in fighting"


tokens_skipgrams(toks, n = 3, skip = 2, concatenator = " ")   
tokens from 1 document.
text1 :
character(0)
```

But the combination of the results gives me exactly what I expected to have, not the one given above.

Is there anyone who can solve this issue for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you are observing is the implementation of Guthrie et al (2006)'s definition of a skiagram: "A *k* skip-gram is an ngram which is a superset of all ngrams and each (*k*-i) skipgram until (*k*-i)==0 (which includes 0 skip-grams)."  (This is cited on the quanteda man page for `?tokens_skipgram`.  The original source is 
[Guthrie, D., B. Allison, W. Liu, and L. Guthrie. 2006. "A Closer Look at Skip-Gram Modelling."](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ballison/pdf/lrec_skipgrams.pdf).). The example of `s02` below is taken directly from that paper, in what it calls "2-skip-tri-grams".

For scalar values of `skip`, however, this recursive implementation of skips is not implemented, in order to give the user maximum control.

This explains the difference in supplying the `skip` values as individual scales as above, and then as the sequence `0:2`.  For

```
toks <- tokens("insurgents killed in ongoing fighting")
toks
# tokens from 1 document.
# text1 :
# [1] "insurgents" "killed"     "in"         "ongoing"    "fighting"
```

we observe combinations such as "insurgents killed fighting" when `skip = 0:2` because this includes the skips of 0 (between "insurgents" and "killed") and 2 (between "killed" and "fighting").  For the phrase here, that means there are only two additional skipgrams from  going from `skip = 0:1` to `skip = 0:2`:

```
(s01 <- tokens_skipgrams(toks, n = 3, skip = 0:1, concatenator = " "))
# tokens from 1 document.
# text1 :
# [1] "insurgents killed in"      "insurgents killed ongoing" "insurgents in ongoing"    
# [4] "insurgents in fighting"    "killed in ongoing"         "killed in fighting"       
# [7] "killed ongoing fighting"   "in ongoing fighting"      

(s02 <- tokens_skipgrams(toks, n = 3, skip = 0:2, concatenator = " "))
# tokens from 1 document.
# text1 :
# [1] "insurgents killed in"        "insurgents killed ongoing"   "insurgents killed fighting" 
# [4] "insurgents in ongoing"       "insurgents in fighting"      "insurgents ongoing fighting"
# [7] "killed in ongoing"           "killed in fighting"          "killed ongoing fighting"    
# [10] "in ongoing fighting"        

setdiff(as.character(s02), as.character(s01))
# [1] "insurgents killed fighting"  "insurgents ongoing fighting"
```